# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number' when i assign two value

Tags: typescript

I am new in typescript, and i am trying to write a simple program, but i got this error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

How can i solve the problem?

file.ts:

```
let aged = true;
let realAge = 0 ;


if (aged) {
  realAge = '4 years';
}

let dogAge = realAge * 7;

console.log(`${dogAge} years`);
```

Comment: Its as the error is saying, find where you are trying to assign a string to a variable that is supposed to be a number. you can do it!

Comment: `realAge = '4 years';` is assigning a string to the variable which should be a number. Which matters because `'4 years' * 7` does not give you a useful number.

Answer (score 1):

That's TypeScript's type checking in action

`let realAge = 0; // here the type of realAge is inferred to number`

...later in the code

`realAge = '4 years'; // the type is now a string`

TypeScript ensures that variables type do not change to values other than the ones set or inferred.

You can create a separate variable to store the 'age caption' like '4 years' which will always be a string and keep the value of `realAge` as a number.

**NOT THE BEST**

If however you want to keep your code working as it currently is, you can set the following

`let aged: boolean = true;`

`let realAge: string | number = 0;`

This however will give you an undesired value, so **maybe it's a bad idea**

`let dogAge = realAge * 7; // weird string multiplication`

Answer (score -1):

The [Type Inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) mechanism automatically assigns types to variables at the declaration and initial assignment time if the type is not specified.

```
let x = 3;   //x  is now of 'number" type.
x = 'foo';   //<- type error
```

This can be avoided by assigning an explicit type during the decleration.

In your case,

```
let realAge: any = 0
```